# How can I find out how many devices support a given certificate?

Tags: ssl, certificate, trusted-root-certificates

We regularly renew the SSL certificate for our web service. With our most recent certificate renewal, we discovered that some legacy/EOL devices (e.g. running Android KitKat) could not access our service, because the new certificate is not trusted by those devices.

We therefore need to know, ahead of time: how many devices will accept this certificate? In other words, what proportion of devices have, in their list of trusted CAs, at least one CA from that certificate's chain?

The output I want might be, for example, "99% of devices trust the certificate with SHA-256 fingerprint `43 48 A0 ...`", or "the certificate `foo.crt` is trusted by Android 4.4+".

We found that [Mozilla Observatory](https://observatory.mozilla.org/analyze/github.com#tls) gives a list of "Compatible Clients" for a given certificate. But it seems that this not accurate, because [it only "compares each server ciphersuite with the ciphersuites supported by the client"](https://github.com/mozilla/tls-observatory/pull/182), rather than consulting the root certificates supported by the client.

Can you recommend a way to determine this support level ahead of time?

Comment: This is a really interesting question but it's wording is attracting close votes. The reason for the close votes are "Off-topic, seeking a product or service". I feel with a few tweaks this could be brought on topic.

Comment: @Burgi the result would probably the same. As you'd need to have detailed information about devices trust stores and possibly the devices themselves. So unless some big budget and manpower is available you'd need to have a service for it. KitKat is ~5-6 years old (and out of scope). Such users should still be able to accept the certificate which would allow them to use the service.

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ Allows to test an HTTPS server. They also calculate the expected usage for different client (protocol, cipher, certificate trusted).